# Allowing the IIS_IUSRS account read/write at parent/root level of inet folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

For months now I've had a headache of having to manually set write permission to my app_data folder after each publication to our test server.

I've decided to set the IIS_IUSRS account to have read/write permissions at the parent level located at c:\inetpub.  This way when I publish it will always inherit this group.

Just interested to know if this is OK, or a no no?  The web server is only used internally by myself so not sharing with any other users/sites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the only person who has access to the server, that is fine, but don't do this on a public server.

`IIS_IUSRS` should not have write access to everything under `c:\inetpub`, just a few specific locations where your web app needs to write to.